# Getting error while importing mnist dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
```

> It throws error with following log

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
E0413 20:50:54.649030 14728 ultratb.py:152] Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-ab413e7a8b2b>", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.datasets import mnist
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .load_backend import epsilon
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
ImportError: cannot import name 'context' from 'tensorflow.python.eager' (C:\Users\Aakash\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1148, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 316, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 350, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Aakash\Conda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
ImportError: cannot import name 'audio' from 'tensorflow_core._api.v2' (C:\Users\Aakash\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall (or update) your Anaconda distribution. Your Tensorflow installation is out to date (or broken). If you continue with the same problem, try installing only tensorflow via pip.

Comment: Thanks jose, It worked when i reinstalled anaconda, tensorfow and keras